# Kendo UI Window undefined by jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, undefined, kendo-window

Facing difficulties to show a Kendo window. While uploading a CSV file I am checking a condition and calling "Import()" function, which should open a window using kendo template. 
but when I try to do that, my jQuery selector cannot find the window and returns "undefined". what should I do to solve it out?

**Script containing div content**

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="templateCondition">
    <div id="details-container">
        <p>*File's road lenght is not equal to selected Road's lenght .</p>
        <p>Are you sure, you want to import the file?</p>

    </div>
    <button class="k-button" id="yesButton">Yes</button>
    <button class="k-button" id="noButton"> No</button>
</script>
```

**Script containing import() function which opens the window**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var generateTemplateWindow = 
    kendo.template($("#templateCondition").html());

    function Import() {
        var wnd = $("#ConfirmationWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        wnd.content(generateTemplateWindow);
        wnd.center().open();

        $("#yesButton").click(function() {
            window.location = "SegIRI/InsertCsvFile";
            wnd.close();
        });

        $("#noButton").click(function() {
            wnd.close();
        });

    }
</script>
```

**Kendo code of window**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("ConfirmationWindow")
  .Title("According to the following condition data will import")
  .Visible(false)
  .Modal(true)
  .Draggable(true)
  .Width(450)
  .Height(100)
)
```

**Conditional function calling**

```
if ((string) TempData["notice"] == "BC")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Import();
    </script>

}
```

[**Screenshot of the error message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JmEw.jpg)

Comment: Does ‘#ConfirmationWindow‘ exist? The ”Kendo code of window" code appears to set name but not id.

Comment: that name should also be id. I used the same thing in another part of my project. only difference is that one is fired by a kendo grid toolbar event and this one is with an independent button

Comment: Maybe you are just missing a ’$(function() {...})’ wrapper around the ’Import()’ call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You might have to specify the id for this one.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ConfirmationWindow" }) 
    .Name("ConfirmationWindow")
    ...
)
```